# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error with ASIHttp framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.4

I have this awkward problem. I am using ASIHTTP framework in my other projects without any problem. I upgraded my XCode to 4.4 and started a new project with ASIHTTP. Imported the files, added `-fno-objc-arc` as usual, but I keep getting these strange messages even though, everything is set up properly. I even tried to copy-paste the whole project to a new one, but no help. I deleted any calls of those classes in my project, no imports, no includes etc. It gives me these errors simply because it is there...

I am targetting on iOS5(iPhone).

Anybody experiencing same thing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `CFNetwork` and `SystemConfiguration` frameworks are linked to your app.

Comment: What a terrible failure...NEVER working on Sundays again. Thank you very much.